# Play Scala Json Writer for Seq of Tuple

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm trying to find a way to use the built in Macro Json Writer in order to serialize Seq[(String,Customer)]

I managed to do this for Seq[Customer] but when adding the touple, the compiler starts screaming at me.

This code works:

```
package models.health

import play.api.libs.json._

case class Customer(name: String, age: Int)

//we use the dummy var as a workaround to the json writer    limitations (cannot handle single argument case class)
case class Demo(customers: Seq[Customer], dummy: Option[String] =    None)

object Demo {

 import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

 implicit val customer_writer = Json.writes[Customer]

 implicit val writes: Writes[Demo] = (
 (__ \ "customers").write[Seq[Customer]] and
 (__ \ "dummy").writeNullable[String]) { 
    (d: Demo) => (d.customers,d.dummy)
 }

}
```

BUT the below code (simply change from Seq[Customer] to Seq[(String,Customer)] Doesn't Copmile... Any help is really appreciated:

```
package models.health

import play.api.libs.json._

case class Customer(name: String, age: Int)

//we use the dummy var as a workaround to the json writer    limitations (cannot handle single argument case class)
case class Demo(customers: Seq[(String,Customer], dummy: Option[String] =    None)

object Demo {

 import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

 implicit val customer_writer = Json.writes[Customer]

 implicit val writes: Writes[Demo] = (
 (__ \ "customers").write[Seq[(String,Customer)]] and
 (__ \ "dummy").writeNullable[String]) { 
    (d: Demo) => (d.customers,d.dummy)
 }

}
```

this is the compiler error I got:

```
No Json serializer found for type Seq[(String,models.health.Customer)]
```

Answer (score 11):

The library makes no assumption as to how you want your tuple to serialize. You could use an array, an object, etc.

By adding this implicit `Writes` function, your serializer will write it out as an array.

```
  implicit def tuple2Writes[A, B](implicit a: Writes[A], b: Writes[B]): Writes[Tuple2[A, B]] = new Writes[Tuple2[A, B]] {
    def writes(tuple: Tuple2[A, B]) = JsArray(Seq(a.writes(tuple._1), b.writes(tuple._2)))
  }
```

Comment: If you upgrade to Play 2.6.1, you don't have to do this anymore - they have a default serialization for this use case.