# What is the most efficient way to map JSON to Scala Objects?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to parse some "complex" JSON with the Play library.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
```

Let's assume I get an array with many JSON objects from a server, that I cannot modify. Each entry looks similar to this one :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "urn": "urn:article:5",
  "key": "post",
  "foo": "useless"
}
```

In the end I want to map this structure into an Scala object with the following values:

- id: Int = 1
- urn: String = "urn:user:5"
- type: String = "article_post" // logic: urn.split(":")(1) + "_" + key

What is the most efficient way? Map the structure within the JSON framework to my needs or should use intermediate case classes as soon as possible to map those into my custom structure?

I looked through the [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson), but they seem not to discuss this problem.

Currently I would create an intermediate case class, that just plucks the relevant attributes (id, urn, key) out of the JSON and map these objects in a following step to a custom my desired structure. I somehow feel this is not the way to go.

Comment: As far as I understood, you need [Json transformers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonTransformers) with validation. With transformers you dont need holder classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this kind of logic in a custom Reads/Writes serializer. See my answer on how to add a custom [JSON Writer for Seq of Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921821/play-scala-json-writer-for-seq-of-tuple). In that case I do a `Writes`, in your case you would create a `Reads` since you are reading JSON and converting to an instance of a class, most likely a case class.

For example

```
case class Wombat(id: Int, urn: String, `type`: String)
implicit val myWombatReads = new Reads[Wombat] {
  def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Wombat] = {
    val id = (js \ "id").as[Int]
    val urn = (js \ "urn").as[String]
    val key = (js \ "key").as[String]
    JsSuccess(Wombat(id, urn, urn.split(":")(1) + "_" + key))
  }
}
```

I didn't test your custom logic, but you get the picture. You can also add validators and such.

Comment: Be careful `as[XXXX]` throws Exceptions.

Comment: Yup, exactly why I suggest validators if you don't control the client.

Answer (score 1):

You need use [Json transformer](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonTransformers)

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json._

val t =  (

  (__ \ "id").json.copyFrom( (__ \ "id").json.pick) and
    (__ \ "urn").json.copyFrom( (__ \ "urn").json.pick) and
    ( __ \ "type").json.copyFrom(
      (__ \ "urn").read[String].flatMap(urn =>
        (__ \ "key").read[String].map(key =>
          JsString(urn.split(":")(1) + "_" + key)
        )
      )
    )
  ).reduce
```

transfomation result for you example:

```
json.transform(t)

scala> json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":1,"urn":"urn:article:5","key":"post","foo":"useless"}

scala> res2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] = JsSuccess({"id":1,"urn":"urn:article:5","type":"article_post"},)
```

Also you can add some validations. Great article for [coast-to-coast desig](http://mandubian.com/2013/01/13/JSON-Coast-to-Coast).